# iOS: Method Return Type should be sub-class of class X

Tags: ios, generics, subclass

I have a class called "BaseEntry" and some specific classes like "EntryFoo" and "EntryBar" which are subclasses from "Base Entry".

Now there is a function getEntry which should return a Object which is subclass of BaseEntry. In Java this wouldn't be a problem but I have no idea how to fix this in Objective-C for iOS.

Thanks for your help!
Alex

Comment: Do you want to write some code that the compiler does not let you? Or do you want to enforce some compile-time type checking on yourself?

Comment: `- (BaseEntry*) getEntry;` does not work?

Comment: Yes - (BaseEntry*) getEntry; does work, but the method should return EntryFoo or EntryBar, because there are specific variables and functions in this classes which are needed.

Comment: Why would this not be a problem in Java? How would you do it there?

Comment: In Java you can return an Object <T extends BaseEntry>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this in Objective-C is to just return an object of type 'id'; think of it as `Object` in Java. However, `id` is slightly nicer in that you can assign the return value to a typed value without a cast.

To clarify, your options are:

```
// Assuming -(BaseEntry*)getEntry;
id entry = [obj getEntry];
[entry messageOnlyOnFooEntry];

// Assuming -(BaseEntry*)getEntry; - note cast required
FooEntry *entry = (FooEntry*)[obj getEntry];
[entry messageOnlyOnFooEntry];

// Assuming -(id)getEntry; - no cast required
FooEntry *entry = [obj getEntry];
[entry messageOnlyOnFooEntry];
```

Comment: This is correct, covariant return types are not supported in objective C they are barely supported in Java.  They are not a design pattern to leverage in OOP.  Return id and cast the pointer according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
BaseEntry gE = [[BaseEntry alloc] init]; // Allocate and init a BaseEntry object
returnGetEntryHere = [ge getEntry]; // This will execute getEntry which is a method in BaseEntry
```

Have you tried anything until now? If you post some code maybe people could help you out with your misunderstandings and shortcomings regarding your objective-c project